# Random numbers on matrix diagonal (possible duplicate)

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to amend this code, so that matrix diagonal would consist of different random numbers?
For now they are the same:

```
    rand_m = np.eye(4, 4, k = 0, dtype=int)
    rand_m[rand_m == 1] = np.random.randint(1, 100)
    print(rand_m)

   [[44  0  0  0]
     [ 0 44  0  0]
     [ 0  0 44  0]
     [ 0  0  0 44]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `size` argument of `randint()` to 4, like this:

```
rand_m = np.eye(4, 4, k = 0, dtype=int)
rand_m[rand_m == 1] = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=4)
```

Answer (score 5):

`randint` can be used to generate a random vector at once. `np.diag` is used to construct a matrix with that vector being the diagonal.

```
np.diag(np.random.randint(1,100,4))
```